# how can i write a function to strip numbers from a text field in msaccess97

Tags: ms-access

I have the following example text in a field representing length x width x height

240 x 346 x 150

34 x 24 x 24

245 x 24 x 150

3.25 x 12.75 x 62

How can i write a function to strip out each number into separate fields for length, width, height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split()` function to split a string into its components, separated by a specific sub-string.

```
Dim Length As Double, Width As Double, Height As Double
Dim a As Variant

a = Split(str, "x")
Length = CDbl(a(0))
Width = CDbl(a(1))
Height = CDbl(a(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Left`, `Mid` and `Right` functions in a new table query should do the trick. Here's some example links for your reference:

```
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/left.php
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php
```